# Dynamic Channel Factory in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I am using the following code in my WCF service to call another web service which may or may not be a WCF service.

```
 ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>
                                                  (myBinding, myEndpoint);
```

So I want to have some information in a xml file from which i read the various services endpoints and want to pass the binding information to the channel factory and call the other services based on the information i have in the config XML file.

So i want to generate the channel factory dynamically using different service contract information every time.

Is it possible in channel factory since various services have different Interfaces?

In other words from the code above I have **IService1** but when i read another service information from an xml file I want to create a channel with another Interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through **Generics:**

```
public static T CreateProxyChannel<T>()
{
    string endpointUri = GetServiceEndpoint(typeof(T));

    ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(myBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpointUri)));

    return factory.CreateChannel();
}
```

And the `GetServiceEndpoint` method to return the endpoint based on the type of T:

```
private static string GetServiceEndpoint(Type service)
{
    string serviceTypeName = service.Name;

    // Code to get and return the endpoint for this service type
}
```

Note that in this case, I expect the config file to have an endpoint associated with the service type name (e.g. `IService1` and `http://localhost/Service1.svc`).

And finally to use it:

```
IService1 serviceProxy1 = CreateProxyChannel<IService1>();
serviceProxy1.MyMethod();

IService2 serviceProxy2 = CreateProxyChannel<IService2>();
serviceProxy2.AnotherMethod();
```

Comment: I want to use a single proxy to call mutiple services  dynamically.I don't want to create serviceProxy1..serviceProxy2....so on..Is it possible ??

Comment: No, a proxy is created based on the service type (the contract). So you need to create a proxy for each service contract before you can execute methods on it. Note that in this case, once the proxy is created, it can be reused. You can follow the Singleton pattern and store it in a factory class.

Comment: What if i want to create a test proxy and reuse the same proxy for a diferent service dynamically passing the service contracts from the XML file instead of creating a proxy for each service ?

Comment: `CreateProxyChannel<T>()` is a generic method and can accept any type, however, once `factory.CreateChannel();` is called and the proxy is created, its type cannot be changed. That is why, for example if you have 4 services, you will need 4 different proxies with different types. Does that make sense?

Comment: Creating 4 different proxies woould equal to adding 4 service references right ? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Correct. The advantage of creating proxies over adding service references is in that you can control the lifetime of a proxy.

Comment: I understand that I wont be able to achieve what i am trying ? I was trying to have a single wcf service which would communicate with any number of other services by just adding few config entries .In other words i don't want to have each proxy for each service and recompile it every time.Wanted to make it as configurable as possible by just adding the endpoints in the config file.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The whole point of having a contract and creating a proxy based on that contract is for the client to know what methods the service offers. Even if there was a way to achieve what you're trying to do, that would make your code extremely vulnerable. You cannot (and should not) have your code completely depend on a config file.

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful to me.Trying to get better at WCF.

Comment: Yes, you can call a WCF service without having the contract interface. Not so easy, but you can dynamically *create* the type and initialize it.:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328552/Calling-a-WCF-service-from-a-client-without-having

Comment: @thepirat000 That is assuming the service exposes its contract type(s) through mex. That's not the case here.